# How to use data-placement in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this following code with data-placement right, based on RTL direction, I want to change data-placement to left how can I use it in CSS?

```
<a href="" class="tooltip-1" data-original-title="<i class='star text-warning fa fa-star-o'></i><i class='star text-warning fa fa-star-o'></i><i class='star text-warning fa fa-star-o'></i><i class='star text-warning fa fa-star-o'></i><i class='star text-warning fa fa-star-o'></i><br>هName<br><img src='' style='width:100%'>" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="right">Name</a>
```

> How can I use data-placement in CSS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not a css property, but a data attribute parsed by the bootstrap javascript file. Secondly, to base the position of the tooltip on the css direction property, you are going to need some javascript/jquery too, plain css will not fulfill your needs in this case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, How to use JavaScript in this case? I've class RTL that based on Language, automatic will change direction, so, based on this class RTL, how to use JavaScript to change tooltip  to left?